# phpmyadmin 5.0.2 Failed to set session cookie

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get "Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin." when I try to login in the phpmyadmin, I have tried to clear the cookies but i still get the error. How can i fix this?

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Comment: If you try to log in a second time after seeing the error, are you successful?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with Chrome extension as I had. In my case extension named Lingvanex.